# Can't access object value, says undefined

Tags: javascript, json, api, object, axios

I am trying to access the value of an object but it appears to me that its value is undefined

If I use `req.body` it shows me the object correctly `{ '{"numeros":"584242549745","mensaje":"qweqwe","files":': [ '' ] }`, but when trying to access its value `req.body.numeros` I get an indefinite value. I don't know what I can be doing wrong here.

Comment: `req.body` is a string. You need to parse it. Probably `JSON.parse(req.body)`, but I expect axios has something built in...

Comment: Are you showing us the entire `req.body`? You have mismatching braces

Comment: currently it looks like an object with a json string as a key and an array with an empty string as its value.

Comment: If you're posting the actual content here, it looks like an object with a property named `{"numeros":"584242549745","mensaje":"qweqwe","files":`; your JSON is most likely malformed. Checkout the single quotes.

Comment: If i use `console.log(typeOf(req.body)` it says it is an object. That´s the weird thing

Comment: _"typeOf(req.body) … it says it is an object"_ — that's an important piece of information, you should add that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the request body with `JSON.parse` or a special middleware. If you use express.js the there is, for example, [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i have already tried that. But is says there is an unexpected token, that's because it is already an object. If i use `console.log(typeOf(req.body))` it says object

Comment: @Joangel De La Rosa, then probably your frontend sends a request with `"numeros":"584242549745","mensaje":"qweqwe","files"` as one param. For example, the params were stringified before sending the actual request.